# jquery sync table width between 2 tables

Tags: jquery, html

Hello all I have 2 tables...anyway in jQuery to make table@ the same width as table 1 dynamically?  If I can set the width of the `td` in table 2 to be the width of the table 1...they will line up perfectly...thanks

```
<table id="t1" align="center" class="data_table" style="border-bottom-style: none;  margin-bottom: 0px;">      
    <tr>        
        <th>        
        </th>    
    </tr> 
</table>  
<table id="t2" align="center" class="data_table" style="border-top-style: none; margin-top: 0px;">       
    <tr>         
        <th colspan="9 title="Source of Repair (SOR) Remarks">SOR Remarks</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>         
        <td width="845px" colspan="9">            
            <textarea name="mcRemark" rows="7" cols="100" scrolling="auto">${mcRemark}   </textarea>        
        </td>    
    </tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
     $('#t2').width($('#t1').width());
```

or

```
     $('#t2 td').width($('#t1').width());
```

I didn't undertand which alternative you were looking for.
Good luck.

Comment: You may want to fix the typos in `.widht()` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should consider also to start using colgroup where you can define any custom style all columns should inherit.. So if you stick to these settings to both of your tables, then that should work like a charm.